# CO/ALR Outlet Wire Mount Screw Torque

Tags: electrical, wiring, aluminum-wiring

When installing a CO/ALR outlet is there a recommended torque specification for the mounting screws? Unfortunately, I have some aluminum wiring in my home.

Comment: Is it not stamped on the receptacle or in the instructions?  "Labeling and instructions" are essential, see NEC 110.3b.

Comment: Not on the one I have. Came in a plastic bag, Leviton #12650. I think I saw them available in boxes too. Perhaps instruction sheet will be included. Think I will check next trip to the store.

Comment: I put some CO/ALR receptacles in my house 40 years ago. I tightened the screws very tight with a standard hand screwdriver that fit well into the slot in the side screws. I checked one recently and it was still tight. Personally I would use AlumiConns and copper pigtails rather than CO/ALR receptacles. Are you aware that code now requires "tamper resistant" receptacles in many places? Do these even come in CO/ALR?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing Alumi-conn connectors (which do have a recommended torque) with CO/ALR. A normal CO/ALR outlet simply needs to be hand tight. I've never seen any specification listed for torque, nor have I ever needed to use my torque screwdriver on one.

Leviton's [CO/ALR installation instructions do not list a recommended torque](https://www.leviton.com/sites/REST/controller/LCDownloadController/download/12650-Instruction-Sheet_EnFr.pdf?docurl=/en/docs/12650-Instruction-Sheet_EnFr.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

### If you need a number, use 14 in-lbs

According to this [2013 IAEI Magazine article on the UL 498 test battery](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2013/09/16/a-journey-back-to-basics-with-receptacles/), when UL is wiring up receptacles during the testing they perform to qualify a receptacle design for the UL listing mark, they torque the receptacle screws to 14 in-lbs, nominal.